# Program crashes when reaching a line

Tags: c++

The program crashes when it reaches `player[aplyr].grid[X][Y] = isSHIP;`

```
const char isSHIP = 'S';

struct PLAYER{

char grid[10][10];

}player[3]; //player 1 and 2. Ignore player 0


int main ()
{
    int X;
    int Y;
    //"PLACE SHIPS" phase of game
    //Loop through each player... 
    for (int aplyr=1; aplyr<3; ++aplyr)
    {
        //Loop through each ship type to place
        for (int thisShip=0; thisShip<15; ++thisShip)
        {       

         //Get input from user
            PlaceShips();

         //Add the FIRST grid point to the current player's game board
            player[aplyr].grid[X][Y] = isSHIP;

        }


            //Loop back until 15 points have been placed
    }
        //Loop back through each player
}

void PlaceShips()
{
    int x, y, player;
    bool goodInput = false;
    do {
         //get X pick
        cout << "Enter X and Y coordinates:  ";
        cin >> x >> y;
        if (x >= 10 && y>=10)
        {
            goodInput = false;
            cin.clear();
            cout << "Out of Range!";
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            goodInput = true;
        }

    } while (!goodInput);  
}
```

Comment: Variables X and Y are never set in the above code. Which means they could contain any value and are more than likely out of bounds of grid. Is this all your code?

Comment: I omitted the wrong parts. I edited it just recently

Comment: X and Y are still not being set in the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the main function you're creating variables X and Y without initializing their value. This means they could contain any value and are more than likely out of bounds of grid. This will cause your program to crash at the specified line.